# MongoDB field increment with max condition in update statement

Tags: mongodb, increment

For MongoDB I'm looking for atomic update that will increment field and if that increment will exceeds maximum given number it will stat that maximum number. Same behavior can be achieved with combination of $inc and $min operators but sadly not in one atomic update. Look at example below.

Example document

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "i": 0
}
```

Queries

```
db.test.update({_id:1}, {$set:{"a":"foo"}, $inc:{i:1}}); db.test.update({_id:1}, {$min:{i:2}});
db.test.update({_id:1}, {$set:{"b":"bar"}, $inc:{i:1}}); db.test.update({_id:1}, {$min:{i:2}});
db.test.update({_id:1}, {$set:{"c":"baz"}, $inc:{i:1}}); db.test.update({_id:1}, {$min:{i:2}});
```

Result document

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "i": 2,
    "a": "foo",
    "b": "bar",
    "c": "baz"
}
```

**Update**

> Thanks to *Christian P* answer I realized that I forgot to mention one more condition. I need document to be updated because I need update more fields than is shown in example. In fact I need increment ceiling (maximum) condition in update statement. I've updated my example to make this clear.

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for a [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) command:

```
db.test.findAndModify({
    query: { _id: 1, i: { $lt: 2 } },
    update: { $inc: { i: 1 } }
})
```

This query will update the document only if `i` is not greater than your maximum given value..

Comment: Thanks for your answer you're right. But I forget to explain in question that I actually need update more fields with query so I can't just exclude any document from update see my question update.

Answer (score 2):

With MongoDB v4.2+, you can simply leverage update with aggregation pipeline. You can simply `$set` the field to be `$min` of the cap and the incremented value.

```js
db.collection.update({
  _id: 1
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "i": {
        $min: [
          {
            $add: [
              "$i",
              1
            ]
          },
          2
        ]
      },
      "a": "foo",
      "b": "bar",
      "c": "baz"
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

Here is the [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qrrQj0TYU_o) for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question, but I absolutely needed this and I was surprised that the atomic solution was not posted.

You have to use a [Transaction](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/transactions/), which essentially creates a virtual session where you can atomically read/write to the database with whatever logic you desire. At the end, you commit the transaction and all the changes you made, or abort it if anything wasn't correct.

Here's a solution using Node.js with async/await ([Node.js Transaction Example](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/transactions/#core-api-implementation))

```js
const session = client.startSession()
try {

    // Begin transaction
    session.startTransaction({
        readConcern: { level: "majority" },
        readPreference: "primary",
        writeConcern: { w: "majority" },
        maxCommitTimeMS: 1000
    })
    let test = client.db('testdb').collection('test')

    // Run your operations in order, always passing the session
    await test.updateOne({ _id: 1 }, { $set: { "a": "foo" } }, {session})

    // Increment if less than 2
    await test.updateOne({ _id: 1, i: { $lt: 2 } }, { $inc: { i: 1 } }, {session})

    // You can do more operations here, reads, writes, etc.

    // If you want to abort the entire transaction, and not commit any of your
    // work, you can throw an error.

    // Commit both operations atomically
    await session.commitTransaction()

} catch (error) {
    // Handle error
    await session.abortTransaction()
} finally {
    await session.endSession()
}
```

The result is that both writes are effectively performed in a single operation. In my case, I needed to update multiple fields with different values, only updating those fields if they would not result in a negative value. If any fields could not be updated, it would inform the user of the unchanged fields. This means I had to use multiple writes with the `$gte` query, however all fields had to be updated atomically. Using a transaction was the solution for me.

I hope this is the solution that works for those with similar problems.

Comment: As long it's in single document, you'd better use update pipeline as shown in the second answer.

Comment: @YaakovShoham of course there was a better answer posted less than 10 minutes after I shared my solution on a 8 year old question. what a coincidence! My use case was to decrement a wallet balance and then add a value to another field, so I really did need to decrement one value without going below zero, then only increase the other value if the decrement worked.