# Mongodb Update a field in a document and then update another depending on the value of previous field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document like this

```json
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("626f942bb092f78afd9dad9d"),
      "item_id": "external _id222",
      "metadata": {
        "item_name": "abc",
        "quantity": 123,
        "state": null
      },
    }
```

What I would like to do is, `$inc` i.e. increment the count of `quantity` and then update the `state` to SOLD, if `quantity` equals 124. I can do this by 2 queries, update `quantity`, do an if-else check and then update `state`. Is there a way to do this in one single query by `update()`? (preferably without aggregation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MongoDB v4.2+, you can do this with a single update with an aggregation pipeline to achieve atomic behaviour. Use `$add` to do the increment and `$cond` to check for quantity = 123

```js
db.collection.update({
  "item_id": "external _id222"
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "metadata.quantity": {
        $add: [
          "$metadata.quantity",
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "metadata.state": {
        $cond: {
          if: {
            $eq: [
              "$metadata.quantity",
              124
            ]
          },
          then: "SOLID",
          else: "$metadata.state"
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/anY_HTYjvb7) for your reference.

Comment: Did I misunderstand the question :O ?

Comment: @Gibbs I am not sure. Actually I just come into [another old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24280144/mongodb-field-increment-with-max-condition-in-update-statement/72312540#72312540) which has a similar scenario but OP of that question actually want to select by some other criteria to perform the update, so I just post my similar answer here to see if it can helps OP here.

Comment: ok, I got your point. let's see what Matt thinks.

Comment: Can't it execute in a waterfall method? In this script, the value increments to 124 but the condition doesn't work, it works in the next iteration when quantity becomes 125. According to my question,  `state` should update when `quantity` becomes 124

Comment: @Matt_crud You can break the aggregation into 2 stages to achieve the "waterfall" behaviour. Updated the answer to demonstrate that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way

1. Check if `quantity` is 123
2. Then increment `quantity` and `set` state to `SOLD`

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/R0b7YNRHXyI)

```
db.collection.update({
  "metadata.quantity": 123
},
{
  "$inc": {
    "metadata.quantity": 1
  },
  "$set": {
    "metadata.state": "SOLD"
  }
},
{
  "multi": false,
  "upsert": false
})
```

Here, the trick is that you need to check the value which is before `$inc` operation.

Comment: the quantity part doesn't need to be the match condition in my case. And i was looking for something like a waterfall way, like update quantity, check if its equal to certain value, if true then update state.

Comment: Then, @ray's answer will help you